# pg_dump not able to connect to rds postgres

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, pg-dump

I am trying to take a dump of the rds postgres in local. I am able to connect to the db via ssh in Dbeaver by localhost:2483

But when I issue the following command in cmd prompt. I am getting the following error. what am I doing wrong

```
pg_dump -v -C -h localhost:2483 -U SSOXXXXX -f dump.sql -d ev_event_db -p 2483 -v
```

Error:

```
pg_dump: error: connection to database "ev_event_db" failed: could not translate host name "localhost:2483" to address: Unknown host
```

**Update:**

```
pg_dump -v -C -h localhost -U SSOXXXX -f dump.sql -d ev_event_db -p 2483 -v...
```

Gives:

> pg_dump: error: connection to database "ev_event_db" failed: server closed the connection unexpectedly This probably means the server terminated abnormally before or while processing the request.

Comment: You are trying to connect to a machine named 'localhost:2483' which doesn't exist.  That is not how you specify a non-default port when using `-h`.

Comment: pg_dump -v -C -h localhost -U SSOXXXX -f dump.sql -d ev_event_db -p 2483 -v........giving pg_dump: error: connection to database "ev_event_db" failed: server closed the connection unexpectedly
        This probably means the server terminated abnormally
        before or while processing the request.

Comment: When I have seen your new error upon connection, it has been because I was connecting through a NAT device that does port forwarding, and the database was not listening.  The  NAT device accepts the connection, then tries to forward it.  But then it gets a connection refused message from the machine it is forwarding to.  Now it is too late to respond upstream with connection refused, as it already accepted it.  So instead it just unilaterally closes the connection.  Something similar to that is probably happening here.

Comment: @sromit Can you connect to the database using `psql`? You should aim to get that working before trying `pg_dump`.